# Translated view (AppBarLayout) is put back in its original position

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm on API 22. The orange view is an `AppBarLayout` inside a `CoordinatorLayout`.
I'm trying to make it disappear by translating it to the top. I want it to get out of the screen.

I'm getting translation height from:

```
AppBarLayout bar;
Rect r = new Rect();
bar.getLocalVisibleRect(r );
float h = r.height();
```

- *Animated* is just a call to `bar.animate().translationY(-h)` and so on; *(tried also ViewCompat.animate(bar), new TranslateAnimation(), ...)*
- *Direct call* is a direct call to `bar.setTranslationY(-h)`.

[image]

Problem is that it gets instantly replaced at its previous place, and translation gets back to 0 (i.e., `bar.getTranslationY() == 0`, even if I have just set it to `-h`). I spent hours on this; you might think

> Maybe it's not possible; CoordinatorLayout is not allowing such behavior

That's not true. The exact same code works *like a charm* on API17, and in last hours I failed to see why it should not on API22. I would appreciate any help, either in understanding why this is not possible, or what's the difference between API17 & API22 that causes this.

Or, maybe, how to get around the problem. Sorry for the low framerate.
(*Side question: should I file a bug report? do you believe it's a bug?*)

Comment: Seems that `AppBarLayout` is holding the total scrolling range and offsets bottom and top to initial values (contrary to your translation). Have you tried to translate it to top, change the scrolling flags, `requestLayout()`, so that `AppBarLayout` exclude `Toolba`r from views that compose the scrolling range?

Comment: @Nikola thanks for commenting. I had tried that but not in that order: I was changing flags, then translating, then requestLayout(). No success. A successful move has been (pseudocoding) `ABL.setBehavior(null)`, then `ABL.translate()`. It is not a pretty solution and I'm working on a more versatile Behavior. I also still see some heavy differences between API17 and API22, particularly in getTranslationY() and similar.

Comment: For my part I got plenty of problems related to `CoordinatorLayout`'s `y` and `translationY` changing by itself when changing its `x` or `translationX`